# Ruby on Rails - What does this symbol mean: <%- ... -%> in erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just generated devise views and found in the generated `erb.html`:

```
<%- if controller_name != 'sessions' %>
  <%= link_to "Sign in", new_session_path(resource_name) %><br />
<% end -%>
```

What does `<%- %> .. <% -%>`, I know it is a monkey's question, but I don't know which keyword to search..so I came to the help of the invincible Stackoverflow..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eats the whitespace so the rendered HTML looks nicer.

Comment: Cool Newton. So I guess it is recommended to use always?

Comment: @larryzhao I don't know; I find I don't look at rendered source very much (preferring DOM browsers) so I'm pretty ambivalent about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can place Ruby code within <% %>

```
<% Ruby code -- inline with output %>
<%= Ruby expression -- replace with result %>
<%# comment -- ignored -- useful in testing %>
% a line of Ruby code -- treated as <% line %> (optional -- see ERB.new)
%% replaced with % if first thing on a line and % processing is used
<%% or %%> -- replace with <% or %> respectively
```

Reference: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html

Comment: Welcome fellow Newton. Doesn't really answer the question, though.