# What does "<%-" do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Came across this recently while working with Devise. I know `<%=` prints, while `<%` keeps results hidden. What does `<%-` do?

Comment: It is rails not Ruby. Erb specifically.  It prints w/o the new line

Comment: I believe this is the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431809/ruby-on-rails-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-erb?rq=1